# AutoCompleteExtender Is not a known Element

Tags: asp.net, ajax, autocomplete, textbox

Although, i write a code with all required lines in  Asp.net , the Autocomplete extender not working ,i dont able to find the reason anyone can teach with code.

The Error i faced

Error    3    Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Error    4    Unknown server tag 'asp:ScriptManager'.
Error    4    Element 'ScriptManager' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site.
Error    5    Unknown server tag 'asp:AutoCompleteExtender'.
Error    5    Element 'AutoCompleteExtender' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head id="Head1" runat="server">

    <title>AJAX AutoComplete</title>

</head>

<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">  

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">

    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <div>   

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCity"

         MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="1" CompletionInterval="1000"

         ServiceMethod="GetCity" >

    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>

    </div>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

AjaxControlToolkit i  installed .  and i want to excecute autocomplete textbox code

Comment: did you add a reference to ajaxtoolkit in your application. Installing does not mean it will be automatically there in your application.

Comment: Hi  Jalpesh Vadgama  ty for your reply, did u mean in web config

Comment: Add reference via right click project -> Add reference -http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: ok ll try and let u know

Comment: hi Jalpesh  its not working..

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Error 1 Element 'AutoCompleteExtender' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site.                                                                 Error 2 WebSite3\Default.aspx: ASP.NET runtime error: Sections must only appear once per config file.  See the help topic <location> for exceptions.                                                           Error 3 Sections must only appear once per config file.  See the help topic <location> for exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its workin now !! becoz of the auto generated bin folder in Vs ..  and also i changed the ajax toolkit version 1.0.20229 For Visual studio 2005...Thank you so much for every one  .. your replies  helped me lot..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have register you ajaxtoolkit as ajaxtoolkit tag on page so instead of using  tag you should use  tag. For example.

```
<AjaxControlToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCity"

     MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="1" CompletionInterval="1000"

     ServiceMethod="GetCity" >
```